# My ajax function doesn't run in certain views

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My ajax doesn't work in my add-passenger view, but when I try it on another view like add-group-passenger it's working. I'm using Codeigniter.

This is my ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#destination").change(function(){
            var destination = $("#destination").val();
            var region = $("#region").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/ci-travel2.0/passanger/getdateprice/',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    destination : destination,
                    region : region
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#date_tour").val(data.date_tour);
                    if((<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>) && (<?= $id_user ?> >= 1)) {
                        $("#price_invoice").val(data.price*<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>-500000*<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>);
                    } else if((<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>) && (<?= $id_user ?> <= 0)){
                        $("#price_invoice").val(data.price*<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>-250000*<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>);
                    } else if((<?= $id_user ?>) >= 1 && !(<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>)){
                        $("#price_invoice").val(data.price-500000);
                    } else if((<?= $id_user ?>) <= 0 && !(<?= $this->session->userdata('jumlah_pax') ?>)){
                        $("#price_invoice").val(data.price-250000);
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is my first view (add-passenger)

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="<?= base_url('passanger/addpassanger') ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="region">Region</label>
                        <select name="region" id="region" class="select2-input region form-control" style="width:100%;">
                            <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                            <?php foreach($region as $r) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $r['id_region'] ?>"><?= $r['region'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?= form_error('region', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                            <select name="destination" id="destination" class="select2-input destination form-control" style="width:100%;">
                                <option value="">-- Select Destination --</option>
                                <?php foreach($destination as $d) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $d['id_destination'] ?>"><?= $d['destination'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?= form_error('destination', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="date_tour">Tanggal Keberangkatan</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_tour" name="date_tour" readonly>
                        <?= form_error('date_tour', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="price">Price Invoice</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price_invoice" name="price_invoice" readonly>
                        <?= form_error('price_invoice', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my second view (group-passenger)

```
div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="<?= base_url('passanger/addgroup') ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="region">Region</label>
                        <select name="region" id="region" class="select2-input region form-control" style="width:100%;">
                            <option value="">-- Select Region --</option>
                            <?php foreach($region as $r) : ?>
                            <option value="<?= $r['id_region'] ?>"><?= $r['region'] ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?= form_error('region', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                            <select name="destination" id="destination" class="select2-input destination form-control" style="width:100%;">
                                <option value="">-- Select Destination --</option>
                                <?php foreach($destination as $d) : ?>
                                <option value="<?= $d['id_destination'] ?>"><?= $d['destination'] ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?= form_error('destination', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="date_tour">Tanggal Keberangkatan</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_tour" name="date_tour" readonly>
                        <?= form_error('date_tour', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="price">Price Invoice</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price_invoice" name="price_invoice" readonly>
                        <?= form_error('price_invoice', '<small class="text-danger pl-3">', '</small>'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

There is no difference between the two views (I think), why does one work and the other not?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: what you mean "My ajax cant work" ? do not send data , do not receive data ? or anything else

Comment: is destination change method working?

Comment: do both views have the same element attributes? do both views have the same php variables?

Comment: there is no console error.
yes, its not receive any data but when i use it on different views its working and there's a data.
nope, if its work then the ajax would success.
yes both have the same attributes, and both do have the same variables.

Comment: can you share your both views ?

Comment: sure, i will edit the question

Comment: details : so i have this 2 views, add-passenger and group-passanger
group-passenger is a loop form that user decide how many it will loop, in my website when user is input how many form will loop, it will create a session named (jumlah_pax) it is for the calculation for the ajax price. Then after user input group-passenger the session will unset, but here's the problem, after the user input how many loop for the form and then go to add-passenger view without unset the session, the ajax price work on the add-passenger but with the wrong result. I think my ajax code only work when there is sess

Comment: If group-passenger is a loop then you will have multiple element with id `destination`. This is not allowed. id must be unique.

Comment: Sorry i dont fully explain what i meant by looping form, the form that i loop is not related to the id that ajax get

Comment: change your url to: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/passanger/getdateprice/' and will work.

Comment: its still not working, my ajax only work if there is session jumlah_pax set